# Standard Controller getRecord() causing Authorization Error in Force.com page

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I have created a Force.com site but I can't access a page with it.

I am getting the error below:
[image]

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="CActions" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
    TEST
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
global class CActions {
    public Case caseObj {get; set;}

    public CActions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        if(controller.getRecord() != null) {
            caseObj = [SELECT Id, Type
                       FROM Case
                       WHERE Id = :controller.getRecord().Id];
        }   
   }
}
```

Few checks that I have done :

- The VF page is set as Active Site Home Page on the site.
- Yes, the page is in the Site Visualforce Pages list.
- Access has been granted on the Apex class via Public Access Settings.
- Case object has Read access.
- Read and Edit rights added on field *Type*.

If I remove

```
if(controller.getRecord() != null) {
    caseObj = [SELECT Id, Type
               FROM Case
               WHERE Id = :controller.getRecord().Id];
}
```

, the page works fine on the Force.com site.
[image]

Note:

Page works great using .../apex/VFP_Test?id=500N0000004c8ts

Does not work with the Force.com site URL : https:// scrmtest.cs6.force.com/VFP_Test?id=500N0000004c8ts

Tried debugging but no luck:

- `System.debug('## controller record : ' + controller );`

gives me

> |USER_DEBUG|[23]|DEBUG|## controller record :
>   ApexPages.StandardController[Case]

- `System.debug('## controller record : ' + (Case)controller.getRecord() );` does not even appear in the log.

Any issue with my code/settings?

Update : Still need help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why getRecord() is not working with force.com site.

But I got my page to work with the following workaround:

I have used the parameter id and have queried the Case.

```
public CActions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    //System.debug('## controller : ' + controller);
    //System.debug('## controller get record : ' + (Case) controller.getRecord() );

    caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    System.debug('## caseId : ' +caseId);

    caseObj = [SELECT Id, Type
               FROM Case
               WHERE Id = :caseId];

    System.debug('## caseObj: ' + caseObj);
}
```

Anyone who run into this issue may use the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by using below class code:

```
   global class CActions {
        public Case caseObj {get; set;}
        public CActions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            caseObj =(Case)controller.getRecord();
            if(caseObj != null && caseObj.Id!=null) {
                caseObj = [SELECT Id, Type
                           FROM Case
                           WHERE Id = :caseObj.Id];
            }   
       }

}
```

There are access issues faced with sObjects in force.com sites and controller.getRecord() returns a sObject. So we can resolve issue by casting it to a Case object.

Comment: Tried it. But not working unfortunately. :( I am still getting 'Authorization Required' page.

Comment: Added a null check for id and now it will work. Make sure a id is passed to site url as {Site URL}?id=<validCaseId>

Comment: Check that your page is available  to the Site Guest User profile, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_public_access_settings.htm&type=0

Comment: @MukeshVerma, it is still not working. I am passing a valid Case Id in URL. My url = < https:// scrmtest.cs6.force.com/VFP_Test?id=500N0000004c8ts >. Note : space after // added on purpose above, to be able to post full link here.

Comment: @Troy, yes it is available. Else, I would not have got 'Test' when I remove the 'if' condition in the class, as mentioned in question. See screen shot attached in my question.

Comment: I didn't think you could access Case objects publicly, wouldn't you need a CRM or Community license to do that?

Comment: Same has been done on another sandbox. It works fine there. I tried comparing but I'm not finding what's missing in my version.

Comment: I updated my question with the debugging part. Still getting same issue.